# Unix permissions

Tags: chmod

I have a file of which I need to change contents, that has these permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

How do I find out which permissions group I belong to, so I can do a chmod command?

I just tried to do chmod and I got an error:

```
$ chmod 777 hosts
chmod: Unable to change file mode on hosts: Operation not permitted
```

Here is my ls -l

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  313 Apr 16 13:04 hosts
```

Comment: Writing `groups` will show which groups you are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'ls -l' will tell you all you need to know.

```
Permissions Directories Group   Size    Date            Directory or file 
drwx------  2           users   4096    Nov 2 19:51     mail/
```

If you have root permission, try a 'sudo chmod 777 hosts'.

Comment: I just updated my question to show the permissions.  Is my owner root...or is group root? I am a bit confused.  Who is the wheel? lol

Comment: Root owns the file in question

Comment: Thanks - got it.  I will accept your answer is 6 min, which is when SO will allow me to accept an answer :)  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help you

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not the owner of the file.

Comment: But how do I find out what permissions group I am in? :)

Answer (score 1):

the owner of the file will need to change permissions or change ownership by using chown,

here are some examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

Answer (score 1):

If you have a super user's password you could always :

```
$ sudo chmod 777 hosts
```

which, of course, is never a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem

Make sure you are the owner of the file
go to the root file, right click then go to more info
at the bottom you can set permissions, hit the plus sign to give your self read + write permissions 
after that hit the gear option and make yourself the owner

in the root file run

```
sudo chmod 777 *
```

if doing this in react native to start up your app run

```
sudo npm start
```

and you should be good to go